# Spark: how to convert rdd.RDD[String] to rdd.RDD[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte])]

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am reading a compressed file in spark using

```
val data =  sc.textFile(inputFile)
```

This gives me data as a `RDD[string]`. 
How to convert this to `RDD[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte])]` in scala?

More details about this requirement:

I am using terasort on spark.  By default terasort does not write compressed output HDFS. 
To fix that issue added following code to TeraSort.scala file

```
sorted.saveAsHadoopFile(outputFile,classOf[Text],classOf[IntWritable],
classOf[TextOutputFormat[Text,IntWritable]],
classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec])
```

This gives me compressed output file

Now I need to read this file to run TeraValidate. 
Teravalidate expects input in `RDD[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte])]` format.

Thanks

Comment: use `data.map(..)` with a function parsing the string into the tuple of Arrays. not enough information supplied for anyone to give any insights into how to write this function...

Comment: How does input text looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the data compressed by passing the compression codec argument to the saveAsTextFile as follows:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
sorted.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/test/", classOf[GzipCodec])
```

You can read this compressed data back using the sc.textFile("/tmp/test/")

[image]

Now, to answer your real question, as Zohar said, you can use the .map to transform your String to Array[Byte], but you haven't given enough information on that.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I am actually working with Spark and Terasort benchmarking application. https://github.com/ehiggs/spark-terasort/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/github/ehiggs/spark/terasort  . And I am trying to change TeraSort.scala and TeraValidate.scala  files to write compressed output and then read the compressed file